# Find revision in trunk that a branch was created from

Tags: svn, branch, revision

I am trying to merge the latest changes from trunk into a branch of my project, but the problem is I don't know what revision of the trunk I checked out that I eventually created the branch from.  I would think SVN logged this somewhere.  Does anyone know how I can find the revision number?

(In other words, the Subversion equivalent of `git merge-base master branch-name`)

Comment: If you're using svn 1.5 or later, you don't need to know this revision number in order to do the merge. `svn merge ^/trunk .` will figure it out for itself. If that's not happening, you might have to `svnadmin upgrade` your repository.

Comment: Hmmm...Subclipse asks for the start revision, I'll have to see if it can do a merge this way

Comment: @slowdog you mean the version of the server, right?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From the command line, the --stop-on-copy flag can be used to help show you where you copied a branch from:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy --verbose --limit 1 -r0:HEAD ^/branches/feature
```

(where `feature` is the name of your branch)

The last line of will say something like this:

```
Changed paths:
   A /branches/feature (from /trunk:1234)
```

Comment: ahh man.  I wish there was a "stop on N copies" option! will have to traverse them manually. thanks!

Comment: I think a svn move will be picked up as a "copy" ... since it is an an copy and delete in one shot.  So if you create a branch, and then rename it (rename as in the tortoise command to rename), it will throw off the "when did this branch start?" data.  I only mention this because "rename" does not sound like "create"......sadly I learned this the hard way.

Comment: The git equivalent of this is so much more logical... `git merge-base master feature-branch`.  And it works well for scripting.

Comment: had to add `--verbose` to actually see the changed path with current TortoiseSVN svn command-line tool

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps a little bit late but.

If you're currently in the branch you can run:

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 --stop-on-copy
```

It displays the first revision of the branch i.e. when you created it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It doesn't list thousands of useless revisions, only to look at the last one.

Comment: I'd suggest adding the `-v` option to the above command so you can also get the `(from path:rev)` message.

Comment: @perkrlsn is there a command that displays just the revision in trunk right before that?

Comment: @BrianStormont could you please help me understand, how is it possible that the revision visible by adding `-v` is the revision not existing in a branch that is mentioned? so for me it says 15.1:860717, while 860717 is not visible in 15.1- it's a commit from 15.0 (another branch)

Answer (score 13):

Are you using TortoiseSvn or command line?

Command Line: `svn log --stop-on-copy` and then look at the smallest rev number.

Tortoise SVN: `right-click, tortoise-svn, show log, make sure 'stop on copy' is *checked* and press refresh. Scroll to the bottom and find the smallest rev number.`
[image]

Comment: actually I was using Subclipse

Comment: Not completely correct. When creating a branch you can specify which revision the branch is based on (using -r) - eg. `svn copy -r 1234 svn://foo.com/trunk svn://foo.com/branches/b1`. The base revision is not necessarily the same as the one at which the branch was created. @richq's answer shows how to get it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used `svn copy` to create a `tag/branch`, then `svn log` can tell you from where your stuff in the branch was copied. For example, let's say we have `svn://svn/trunk/foo` and we have created a branch `svn://svn/branches/super_foo`. Run `svn log -v svn://svn/branches/super_foo`, it will tell you something like this - `/branches/super_foo from /trunk/foo:22890`, which means that you have copied revision 22890 of trunk into your branch.

Answer (score 0):

For the Cornerstone app, to see where a tag or branch originated, look in the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

To see changed paths with current TortoiseSVN command-line tool and to query repo without having local checkout run this (from any directory)

`svn log --stop-on-copy --limit 1 --verbose -r0:HEAD "http://server:9876/svn/reponame/branches/branch name"`

Notice `--verbose` to actually show the changed paths and explicit repo/branch URL to avoid having to check it out