# Subversion (SVN) branching

Tags: svn

I want to branch from the trunk at a previous revision. After my `svn copy` command with the @REV addition, I checkout the branch-REV to a new directory and when I do a `svn info` in that directory it shows the revision of the current trunk HEAD.

How do I determine if my branch is at wanted previous version REV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want confirmation that your `svn copy` command was correct by looking at the `svn info`. This doesn't work the way you expect. As you've just branched, it's going to show the last "revision" as the current (which is when the branch happened), since there are no changes in the branch.

I think what you want to do is this ([copied directly from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258283/svn-find-revision-in-trunk-that-a-branch-was-created-from)):

`svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy $REPOSITORY/branches/feature`

The last line of will say something like this:

```
Changed paths:
   A /branches/feature (from /trunk:1234)
```