# Find revision in trunk that a branch was created from using SVNKIT

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

I trying to get the revision which a branch was created from using svnkit but I don't know how to achieve that. That I need is something like that the command line in this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258283/find-revision-in-trunk-that-a-branch-was-created-from#_=_)

If you have an example code to do this with svnkit, it will be very useful for me.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION

This code fragment is posting on this [site](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/Discovering-creation-date-of-a-folder-td2596.html). This code returns the revision which a branch was created from.

```
final long[] revStart = { -1 }; 

logClient.doLog(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(
"https://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/branches/1.2.x"), 
null, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.create(1), true, 
false, false, 0, null, new ISVNLogEntryHandler() { 
public void handleLogEntry(SVNLogEntry logEntry) throws 
    SVNException {
       System.out.println(logEntry);
       revStart[0] = logEntry.getRevision();
    }
}); 

System.out.println(revStart[0]);
```