# How to find changes done to a branch created from trunk in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, branch

Lets say I had created a SVN branch `Repo2018x` out of branch `Repo2018`. Now after that, `Repo2018` received commits say A and B, while `Repo2018x` received commits C and D. I want to see the code diff of the list of commits done to `Repo2018x` post its creation i.e. changes collected from commits C and D.

FYI, I am able to get the [log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258283/find-revision-in-trunk-that-a-branch-was-created-from) but that's not something I want :

```
svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy $REPOSITORY/branches/feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another branch from the actual Repo2018, change into it, merge (w/o commit) the branch Repo2018x into it, review what was changed?

==> gets you changes of branch Repo2018x to your actual one

If you want the complete diff to the "original" version you branched from, you can create a branch from this. Or use a diff to that specific revision.